# What is this type of piano sound and playing style?

Tags: piano, digital-piano, sound, styles, sound-design

I can't find out what is the name of this type of piano playing, it sounds really great and seems popular. Thanks, and I appreciate it!

Comment: I don't see a piano in the second video.

Comment: @phoog can just about hear one though

Comment: @AakashM fair enough. I was too busy looking to listen.  And in fact you can see it in the background at around 1:30.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe just pop rock piano. There are hints of Jerry Lee Lewis, general funk, a bunch of simple arpeggios and scales such as chromatic, Ionian, Mixolydian, blues and of course a gliss or two. It is not so much what he played but how he played it.  The kid is very good at grooving and jamming.  The sax players are very good, too.  They should have swapped fours then changed keys back at the head. That would have knocked it out.  I'm gonna steal some of those sax lines.